# Greedy Activity Selection Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

I am trying to solve this problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/classrooms

> There are  classrooms on campus and  proposed activities that need
> to be assigned a venue. Every proposed activity has specific starting
> time  and ending time . Any such an activity should take place
> at one of the classrooms. Any of the  classrooms is big enough to
> hold any of the proposed activities, and each classroom can hold at
> most one activity at any time. No two proposed activities can take
> place at the same classroom at the same time. Even if two proposed
> activities overlap momentarily (the ending time of one activity equals
> the starting time another activity), they cannot be assigned to the
> same classroom.
>
> There are so many proposed activities that there may not be enough
> classrooms to hold all the activities. It is desirable to have as many
> activities as possible. At most how many proposed activities can be
> assigned to the classrooms?
>
> Input The first line contains two positive integers  and 
> (1≤≤≤200000), representing the number of proposed activities and
> number of classrooms, respectively.
>
> The following  lines each contains two positive integers: the th
> line among these  lines contains  and  (1≤≤≤109),
> indicating the starting time and ending time of proposed activity

I have come up with a greedy solution where I sort the classes by end time, then check if it's possible to allocate a class to an activity based on greedy conditions

```
'''
https://open.kattis.com/problems/classrooms
'''

from collections import deque

n, k = map(int, input().split())
classes = []
for _ in range(n):
    (start, end) = map(int, input().split())
    classes.append((start, end))

classes.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
queue = deque()
count = 0
for (start, end) in classes:
    if queue and queue[0] < start:
        queue.popleft()
        queue.append(end)
        count += 1
    elif len(queue) < k:
        count += 1
        queue.append(end)
print(count)
```

However, this fails on a few (hidden) test cases.

What's the right approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Doesn't it input the total time?

Comment: @brandon not sure I understand. The inputs are a bunch of start and end times for each activity

Comment: Do you just know that it fails at those test cases and not what fails?

Comment: yes, I don't know the test-cases for which it fails

Comment: Did you check this kind of input: 1 class, 3 activities, 1 9, 2 3, 5 6 ?

Comment: @Damien input `3 1; 1 9; 2 3; 5 6` works fine. Since the activities are sorted by end-time, the first choice is 2 3, then 5 6 replaces it in the queue and 1 9 is skipped.

Comment: You are right. Need to find a more sophisticated failure scenario @גלעדברקן

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example of how the current procedure could fail.

8 activities, 2 classrooms:

```
  a   b   c
 --- --- ------
 d     e
--- -------
  --- ---- ---
   f   g   h

queue   count
 d       1
 d a     2
 f (no)
 a b     3
 b g     4
 e (no)
 g h     5
 c (no)
```

We can clearly see that the result could be 6, using the top and bottom tracks.

Here's the corresponding input:

```
8 2
2 4
6 8
10 15
1 3
5 11
3 5
7 10
12 14
```

I think a good avenue for exploration is along the lines you proposed except have k buckets (rather than just one) into which we'd like to keep choosing to create the next least end-time.

Comment: Note that (d b c) (a g h) seem a valid 6-solution. So the problem may be to which classrooms are the activities affected, not only the activities selection. In your simulation of the algorithm, could you detail this point ? I guess we should select the "more advanced (recently busy)" classroom

Comment: @Damien I'm not sure what you mean. I only simulated the OP's current method and how it would fail. I did allude in the end to what I thought would be useful to consider.

Comment: Basically, I mean what you just added! For a given activity, I guess we should select the classroom (what you call bucket?) with the highest last activity time. I understood that you only provided an example of good solution. I wanted to emphasize that the current algorithm is not very far from the best solution

Comment: @Damien yes, I agree the current solution does not seem too far.

Comment: thanks, great solution. Any ideas on how to implement the algorithm with time complexity better than n^2?

Comment: @nz_21 haven't tested but I'd try k buckets (meaning just the last end time there, so k single variables) and maintain either a single variable of the bucket with the least end time to place the next candidate in, or a tree informing us of the bucket with greatest end time still lower than the candidate.